# Ubuntu 22.04 - Bluetooth earbuds noise from time to time

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, lenovo, headphones

I have Ubuntu 22.04 as my only OS, installed on a Lenovo IdeaPad 3. The topic is about my Redmi Buds 4 pro, a mid-range bluetooth earbuds from xiaomi, wich btw they don't have problems on other devices.

I can connect them normally and all, but very frequently I experience a lot of noise, like the one CRT's use to make on no signal, when something is loading or I interact with anything. If I click on a tab on my browser it start to get noisy. It's like a workload problem. To be said that Stancer CPU use still show's like 3% usage.
Sometimes Im just watching something on the browser and it enters on this malfunctioning state and then it stops or sometimes it still going like that until I restart the notebook or whatever. I really have no clue on how to fix it. I reinstalled PulseAudio and Bluez but no luck.

> - Adress: 6C:D3:EE:6E:B9:15 ;
> - Adress Type:
>   public ;
> - Name: Redmi Buds 4 Pro ;
> - Alias: Redmi Buds 4 Pro ;
> - Class: 0x240404 ;
> - Appearance: 0x0000 ;
> - Icon: audio-headset ;
> - Paired: yes ;
> - Trusted: yes ;
> - Blocked: no ;
> - LegacyPairing: no ;
> - RSSI: -55 dBm (0x-37);
> - Connected: yes ;
>
> > - UUIDs:
> >   00000000-0000-0000-0099-aabbccddeeff Privative
> >   00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Headphones
> >   0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Audio Receptor
> >   0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Remote Control Focus
> >   0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Advanced Audio
> >   0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Remote Controle
> >   0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Free Hand
> >   00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Info of PnP
> >   0000fd2d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb Unknown
> >   0000ff01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34ff Privative

> - Modalias: bluetooth:v0094p0004d0100 ;
> - Adapter: /org/bluez/hci0 ;
> - ManufacturerData: {911: [22, 1, 16, 69, 110, 40, 41, 1, 137, 166, 186, 211, 108, 238, 103, 126, 111, 49, 211, 108, 238, 21, 185, 110], 19802: [8, 3, 2, 234, 15, 21, 185, 110, 238, 8]}